Issue with opening of web notifications from twitter in chrome
I am getting web notifications from twitter from chrome in Windows 11 desktop. They appear in the right bottom of the screen and I can see last 20 notifications.
When I click this notification it opens it in chrome provided no other twitter Tab is open in chrome. Else the already open chrome twitter Tab flashes but it fails to show this notification in twitter in detail.The notification is lost in this process.
So every time I have to remember to close the last twitter Tab in chrome for this and many times I forget to do so.
Any change in permissions is needed to let more twitter tabs get opened from this notification.

I have the same problem Windows 11 here and I have extra things to tell :

happened about 6 days
X notifications appear, but when I click them they open the twitter
tab on chrome but doesn't get the clicked twit ( the old twit still
appear )
I tried to switch push notifications off from twitter setting and
turned off and vaniche
the solution was to use brave setting option ( Use Google
services for push messaging) then the push button appeared
the same problem happened in Brave too, but with one thing in
a difference that I can, turn off and on the push notification button
in Brave as many times as i want
I tried twitter app from MS store , the same  and tried to see the
push notification button on Edge and it doesn't appear just like
chrome.
the final situation is the same notification pop-up, but when I
click them they open the twit tab in brave but doesn't update the
clicked twit )

I really can't understand if this is a windows or twitter or chrome bug?   but I sent it here cause it's the only place that stated the problem I had exactly 6 days ago.
I also had the same error submitted here guys,  hope we can solve it
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/twitter-push-notifications-on-any-browser-option/477a0dd7-6fe4-485d-951e-11b6d8fc65f5?page=2
PS: I cleared cash and even reset chrome browser setting and still have the same issue
hope my feedback help u guys to solve the problem

problem solved with chrome updated to latest version
Version 125.0.6422.61 (Official Build) (64-bit)
